# How to execute python command in sh script

Tags: python, sh, freebsd

In a FreeNAS I'm trying to execute in the directory /urllib3 the command

```
python setup.py install
```

inside a jail from an sh script.

If I enter the jail

```
iocage console jailname
```

and then type the commands

```
cd /urllib3

python setup.py install
```

it works.  I can't figure out how to code this in the sh script.

When I run the command outside the jail as a test to include in my script

```
iocage exec jailname "python setup.py install"
```

I get the error

```
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
```

I've also tried

```
iocage exec jailname "/urllib3/python setup.py install"
```

that gives the error

```
/bin/sh: /urllib3/python: not found.iocage exec jailname python /urllib3/setup.py install
```

trying

```
iocage exec jailname "python /urllib3/setup.py install"
```

gives the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/urllib3/setup.py", line 18, in <module> with codecs.open("README.rst", encoding="utf-8") as fp:  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 897, in open
file = builtins.open(filename, mode, buffering) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.rst'
```

Comment: Try `iocage exec jailname "cd /urllib3 && python setup.py install"`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
iocage exec jailname "cd /urllib3 && python setup.py install"
```

You need to go to the directory and then install python.